# Write TDD test with Mock for Web API project with dot net 6.0 and Unit Of Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, moq, webapi, web-api-testing

I have a **Web API** project, I use **Unit Of Work** pattern with dot net 6.0 and want to write test for it.

I have a controller like below and a function in it for authentication:

```
public AuthController(IUnitOfWork uow, IStringLocalizer<SharedTranslate> localizer, IJwtAuthenticatorManager jwtAuthenticatorManager) : base(uow, localizer)
{
    //...
}

[HttpPost("authenticate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] UserLoginViewModel Request)
{
    User user = await _uow.UserRepository.GetAsync(u => u.Username == Request.Username);
    //...
}
```

For a unit test with Moq, I use below code:

```
var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
 unitOfWork
 .Setup(uow => 
 uow.UserRepository.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>()))
.ReturnsAsync(new User());
var localizor = new Mock<IStringLocalizer<SharedTranslate>>();
var jwtManager = new Mock<IJwtAuthenticatorManager>();
var controller = new AuthController(unitOfWork.Object, localizor.Object, jwtManager.Object);
UserLoginViewModel userLoginViewModel = new UserLoginViewModel
{
    Username = "test",
    Password = "test"
};
var result = await controller.Authenticate(userLoginViewModel);
```

When I debug it, it can't connect to to database (for example the object user in the Authenticate function is empty) and check.

1.What is the problem?

2.Is this method good for test?

Comment: Which database?

Comment: In the controller, function Authenticate, I check the username and password with the database that is information correct and then create JWT token.

Comment: It sounds as though you have existing code that you want to unit test. That's common, but not TDD, so I'll remove the [tdd tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdd). I'll add the _moq_ tag, though, as it looks as though you are using Moq.

Comment: I'm guessing that the username and password check against the database somehow isn't handled by one of the injected dependencies, but without more information, I can't say more than that. Please edit the question so that it includes a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkSeemann in the function Authenticate I have a line that get User "User user = await _uow.UserRepository.GetAsync(u => u.Username == Request.Username);" the user is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unitOfWork.UserRepository` is going to be `null` by default, and even if it not, Moq doesn't know what to return when the `GetAsync` method is called. You have to tell it:

```
var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
unitOfWork
    .Setup(uow => uow.UserRepository.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new User());
```

This assumes that `GetAsync` is defined like this:

```
Task<User> GetAsync(Func<User, bool> predicate);
```

If not, adjust as required.

Comment: I edited the question according to your code, now the user object is not NULL but it's empty, means it doesn't have any data and the fields have the default value.

Comment: @JohnS yes, you'll need to change the `new User()` expression to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Means for each test, I'll need to know what I want? Is this way correct way for testing Web API or there is another way for it?

Comment: @JohnS If you don't know what you want, then who does?

Comment: I know! It means we can't connect to the database and we should specify what data should return. In this way, if we want to test a report and know that the result is correct or not, we can't, right?

Comment: @JohnS I'm not sure that I understand the question, but when using [Test Doubles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) ('mocks') then you've deliberately excluded the 'real' dependency (here, the database). You can write automated tests that integrate with databases, too, but then you don't use Test Doubles.